# matplotlib animation ArtistAnimation failure due to ffmpeg unavailable

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to call matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation to make an animation from a series of png images, but I get an error that is connected to the ffmpeg. I have Anaconda installed on my Ubuntu 14.04. The error message that I get is:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:782: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
...
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 810, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 196, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 389, in finish
    + ' Try running with --verbose-debug')
RuntimeError: Error creating movie, return code: 1 Try running with --verbose-debug
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, but there is no such package. Someone knows what package I'm missing?

Comment: Strange that it isn't there. Check if you have anything that's named similarly: `apt-cache search ffmpeg`. Prior to that, update your package-list.  In any case, `ffmpeg` is in my apt-package list, but I'm on a different distro.

Answer (score 4):

```
conda update conda
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge ffmpeg
```